# How to deal with constant episodes of forgetfullness

Tags: psychology

I have been working on a task for 2 weeks.
There was no stress.
i was going well into the details and making good conclusions.

Yet, yesterdya we had a demo on the work and when asked about some specific qtn, i realized i didnt remember doing some piece of task.
My colleagues said i had. but i didnt remember at all. i was blank . as if it never happened. but this kind of stuff has been happening to me lately and i thought hard. i realized i MAY have done it. but am still not sure.

also, i knew todays date: (16th) but for sm reason i forgot that yesterdays date is (15th)

i mean something is truly wrong with me.

I am considering going to a Doc, but not sure.

Please advice

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is  asking for medical advice

Comment: When in doubt, consult a professional.

Comment: By lunch time, I can't remember what I ate for breakfast - That's perfectly normal to me. There is no way for us to make any determination as to whether your condition is normal. We are not medical professionals and almost every medical professional would be reluctant to say anything unless they see you inperson, I can't fathom why you would want to consult us about a possibly medical condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If poor memory is a regular problem seeing a doctor is not a bad idea as it could be a symptom of a bigger problem.

That said, we all forget things from time to time. (some are better than others) so don't fret to much when it happens, but constantly needs to be addressed.

There are TONS of games out there specifically designed to develop and improve your long term and short term memory as well as recognition skills. Typically these games require you to remember more and more at a time until you hit your limit. Through practice you'll eventually push on to the next level, repeat. These memory exercises have been proven to have profound affects on our memory over time.

That said do your home work some of these games are really good and free, some of them are really crappy and expensive. Essentially you want to practice things that make you think and remember. The more you work your brain the better it'll perform when you need it (so long as you get enough sleep)